# Buffered input to SecTransform

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I'm reading data from an audio file and computing a hash of it, as in the style of the [ffmpeg MD5 muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#md5-1), except I'm doing SHA2 and using AVFoundation and the OS X `SecTransform` API.

What this does is it opens an audio file, converts it into it's native PCM format if it's compressed, and then hashes the interleaved samples byte-by-byte.

When I read the audio from my files, I would normally read the samples into a buffer in a `for` or `while` loop.

```
extension AVAudioFile {
    func sha2() throws -> NSData {

        let bufSize = AVAudioFrameCount(0x1000)
        let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(PCMFormat: self.processingFormat,
            frameCapacity: bufSize)

        // initialize digest algo

        for(;;) {
            try readIntoBuffer(buffer)
            if buffer.frameLength > 0 {
                // read buffer into digest
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
    // finalize digest and return...
    return NSData()
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is, the only way I can see of loading data into a `SecTransform` is either handing it all the data at once in a `CFData`, or as a `CFReadStream`.  How do I feed my data buffer-by-buffer into a `SecTransform`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you create bound input and output streams with `NSStream.getBoundStreamsWithBufferSize()` and then you feed the output stream with an asynchronous loop

The complete implementation is like this:

```
func writeSamplesFromBuffer(buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, toStream : NSOutputStream) {
    assert(buffer.format.interleaved == true)
    var rawBuffer = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(buffer.int32ChannelData.memory)
    var toWrite = sizeof(Int32) * 
        Int(buffer.format.channelCount) * Int(buffer.frameLength)
    while toWrite > 0 {
        let written = toStream.write(rawBuffer, maxLength: toWrite)
        rawBuffer = rawBuffer.advancedBy(written)
        toWrite -= written
    }
}

func writeAudioDataFromURL(url : NSURL,
    usingFormat format: AVAudioCommonFormat,
    toStream: NSOutputStream) throws {

        let audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: url,
            commonFormat: format,
            interleaved: true)

        let pcmBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(PCMFormat:
            audioFile.processingFormat,
            frameCapacity: 0x1000)

        toStream.open()

        let writerQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY, 0)
        dispatch_async(writerQueue) {
            while true {
                do {
                    try audioFile.readIntoBuffer(pcmBuffer)
                    if pcmBuffer.frameLength > 0 {
                        writeSamplesFromBuffer(pcmBuffer, toStream: toStream)
                    } else {
                        break
                    }
                } catch let error {
                    fatalError("Fatal error: \(error) while reading audio file \(audioFile) at URL \(url)")
                }
            }
            toStream.close()
        }
}

func sha256DigestForStream(stream : NSInputStream) throws -> NSData {
    let transform = SecTransformCreateGroupTransform().takeRetainedValue()
    let readXform = SecTransformCreateReadTransformWithReadStream(stream as CFReadStreamRef).takeRetainedValue()

    var error : Unmanaged<CFErrorRef>? = nil
    let digestXform = SecDigestTransformCreate(kSecDigestSHA2, 256, &error).takeRetainedValue()

    SecTransformConnectTransforms(readXform, kSecTransformOutputAttributeName,
        digestXform, kSecTransformInputAttributeName,
        transform, &error)
    if let e = error { throw e.takeUnretainedValue() }

    if let output = SecTransformExecute(transform, &error) as? NSData {
        return output
    } else {
        throw error!.takeRetainedValue()
    }
}

func sha256DigestForAudioFile(url : NSURL,
    convertedToSampleFormat sampleFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat) throws -> NSData {

        let streamBufSize = 0x1000
        var rs : NSInputStream? = nil
        var ws : NSOutputStream? = nil

        NSStream.getBoundStreamsWithBufferSize(streamBufSize,
            inputStream: &rs, outputStream: &ws)

        guard let readStream = rs, writeStream = ws else {
            fatalError("Failed to create file read streams")
        }

        try writeAudioDataFromURL(url,
            usingFormat: sampleFormat, toStream: writeStream)

        return try sha256DigestForStream(readStream)
}
```